how to add a N/A button inside the dateRangeFilter in the header of a webix dataTable that will filter out N/A values in that column?
`webix.ready(function(){
    grid = webix.ui({
        container:"tracker",
        editaction:"click",
        editable:true,
        view:"datatable",
        css:"webix_header_border", 
        leftSplit:1,
        columns:[
            {% for column in program_fields %}
                { 
                    id:"{{ column }}", 
                    header:[
                        { text:"{{ column|external_name }}",  css:"multiline" }, 
                        {% if column in program_date_fields %}
                            { content:"dateRangeFilter" }
                        ],
                        sort:"date",
                        {% if column in editable_fields %}
                            editor:"date",  
                            fixed: true,
                        {% endif %}
                        template: function (obj, common) {
                            if (obj.{{ column }} === null || obj.{{ column }} === "") {
                                {% if column in program_na_fields %}
                                    return `<div class="date-cell" >
                                                ${webix.i18n.dateFormatStr(obj.{{ column }})}
                                                {% if column in editable_fields %}
                                                    <span class="webix_icon wxi-pencil">
                                                        - 
                                                        <input class='nabtn' type='button' value='N/A' na-date-column='{{ column }}' style='font-size: small;'>
                                                    </span>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>`;
                                {% else %}
                                    {% if column in editable_fields %}
                                        return common.editIcon(obj, common);
                                    {% else %}
                                        return "";
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                            } else if (obj.{{ column }} < new Date(1901, 0, 1)) {
                                return "N/A";
                            } else {
                                return `<div class="date-cell">
                                            ${webix.i18n.dateFormatStr(obj.{{ column }})}
                                        </div>`;
                            }
                        }
                    {% endif %}
                },
            {% endfor %}
        ],
        select:"row",
        scroll:"xy",
        hidden:false,
        resizeColumn:true,
        headermenu:true,
        data: data,
    });
});
`

my datatable is using the webix library where I want to add a custom N/A button inside every column specific datarange filter which will filter out all the N/A values in that column. Currently Jan 1900 date filters out these N/A values but we need a button(or any other straight forward way) that will perform this, instead having to choose the date Jan 1900 to find the N/A column values.`

Try to change header section
                    header:[
                    { text:"{{ column|external_name }}",  css:"multiline" }, 
                    {% if column in program_date_fields %}
                        { content:"dateRangeFilter" },
                        { 
                            template: function(){ 
                                return "<button class='nabtn'>N/A</button>"; 
                            },
                            width: 50,
                            css: "webix_header_button",
                            click: function(){
                                var columnId = this.config.id;
                                grid.filter(function(obj){
                                    return obj[columnId] !== "N/A";
                                },{ column: columnId });
                            }
                        }
                    {% endif %}
                ],

